# How to ask for connection string in clickonce installer?

Tags: c#, connection-string, clickonce

Is there anyway to configure clickonce so it prompts to the user fill the connection string for the application?

Like, I'll deploy my application for many users, and in each case the sql server will get an instance name, maybe diferent, and the host will sure be diferents. So how can I configure it to get on installing the right connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two approaches here - either when you're starting application check if connection string is presented in application settings; and if it isn't ask user for giving you one (be sure to store application settings in isolated storage).

If you want it automatically, and your're hosting your app on web server, you can pass the connection string as part of activation url (instead of /ClickOnce.application direct user to page /ClickOnce.application?ConnectionString=My_Encoded_ConnectionString) and from the app itself you can read it like this

```
  try {
    if (ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment == null ||
      ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri == null)
      return null;
  } catch {
    // application was not activated from the web
    return null;
  }

  Uri uri = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri;
  string query = uri.Query;
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri.Query))
    throw new UIException("Activation Uri is empty.");

  Regex regex;
  Match match;
  regex = new Regex(@".*ConnectionString=(?<ConnectionString>([A-Z0-9\+/=:%\._-]+))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  match = regex.Match(uri.Query);
  if (match == null || !match.Success) {
    throw new UIException("ConnectionString not recognized as part of activation Uri.");
  }
  return HttpUtility.UrlDecode(match.Groups["ConnectionString"].Value);
```

Comment: if i put it on activation url and allow the user to execute it offline, it can get errors right? I think the best will be at the first time in application I ask it... thanks

Comment: That is correct. You can combine those approaches (i.e. if application is web-activated, store the connection string in your settings, and read it from there). At least first run should be web activated (if you're hosting the installation on web server only).

Comment: Ill have to make it avaliable offline too.. so, I think its better to use just one aproach. Thanks ^^